# Land allocation to polygons with specific areas within a boundary

Tags: qgis, area, polygon-creation, computational-geometry

We are looking for a solution to create novel land allocations of an existing area into a subset of polygons for each allocation within the existing space.

A high level overview of the requirements are:

- The boundary of the land to be allocated will be defined as a GeoJSON feature set and may be made up of a number of polygons.
- Each allocations within the boundary are to be made to an account and will be provided in m². Sizes of the account allocations may range in size from 1 to several 1000's m².
- Visually we would prefer for the allocations to be made in convex polygons with a resulting shape that is similar to a voronoi diagram. Given that the boundaries may be concave polygons it will be acceptable for an area polygon allocated on a boundary to be concave.
- Over time the land allocated to different accounts will change. Existing accounts will allocate more land and new accounts will be allocated until the whole boundary space is eventually filled. - Ideally we should be able to plot a timeseries of these allocations over time and see individual allocations grow/change. Ideally we would try to keep an allocation in the same general area of within the boundary over time, however we accept that things need to move to make room.
- Given that we are dealing with irregular polygons we understand that an exact area is not going to be possible in all cases so we would be happy if the actual area of the allocated polygon is within 1% of the actual allocation.
- Each boundary may end up with 10's of thousands of allocations and the creation of an area allocation polygon needs to be able to be executed as quickly as possible.

Note that we initially tried to do implement this directly in JavaScript using turf.js library, however we have identified that using a program such as QGIS may be a better approach.

We would really appreciate any guidance you may be able to provide in terms of approaches in QGIS or even general algorithms that we could apply to achieve this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.